# Can't compile SFINAE in Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

struct X {};
struct Y {};

__int8 f(X x) { return 0; }
__int16 f(...) { return 0; }

template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<sizeof(f(T())) == sizeof(__int8), int>::type call(T const& t) {
    std::cout << "In call with f available";
    f(t);
    return 0;
}

template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<sizeof(f(T())) == sizeof(__int16), int>::type call(T const& t) {
    std::cout << "In call without f available";
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    Y y; X x;
    call(y);
    call(x);
}
```

Seems to be a pretty simple use of SFINAE here, but the compiler throws an error, which is that it can't instantiate `enable_if<false, int>::type`. Any suggestions? Apparently this code compiles just fine on GCC (didn't ask which version).

Edit: This code compiles fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

struct X {};
struct Y {};

__int8 f(X x) { return 0; }
__int16 f(...) { return 0; }

template<typename T> struct call_helper {
    static const int size = sizeof(f(T()));
};

template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<call_helper<T>::size == sizeof(__int8), int>::type call(T const& t) {
    std::cout << "In call with f available";
    f(t);
    return 0;
}

template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<call_helper<T>::size == sizeof(__int16), int>::type call(T const& t) {
    std::cout << "In call without f available";
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    Y y; X x;
    call(y);
    call(x);
}
```

So I'm perfectly happy to chalk this one up to being a bugarooney.

Comment: @DeadMG: what is the errror. Is the call( y ) or call( x ) or is it on one of the template-definition (which one)

Comment: Comeau reports `error: no instance of overloaded function "call" matches the argument list`.  Visual C++ doesn't even like the definitions of the first overload.  Interesting.

Comment: @DeadMG: try a third function __int16 call (int i) { return 0; } then you'll known it's probably then variadic argument call( ... )

Comment: The error doesn't specify which call throws an error. It isn't a problem with variadic argument, partly because I've used this before, and partly because I replaced it with a template accept-all instead and that made no difference.

Comment: i watched this video (http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-10-of-10) and at the end it is said (if i remember correctly) ,the compiler only instatiates when types are matched exactly (on the eneable_if part that is).

Comment: After a couple of tweaks g++-4.0.3 barfed a nice compiler error: `sfinae.cpp:36: sorry, unimplemented: call_expr cannot be mangled due to a defect in the C++ ABI`, then after moving the `sizeof(f(T())) == sizeof(__int8)` into its own class template instead of having the check as the first argument to `enable_if`, it compiled fine. Still, I am amused with the error :)

Comment: I found a solution, but I can't explain why it works and the original code doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles and works correctly in VS2010.  Modified using suggestion by David.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
  typedef X is_x;
  };
struct Y {};

__int8 f(X x) { return 0; }
__int16 f(...) { return 0; }

template < class T >
struct test {
  enum { result = sizeof(f(T())) };
  };

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< test<T>::result == sizeof(__int8), int>::type call(T const& t) {
    std::cout << "In call with f available" << std::endl;
    f(t);
    return 0;
}

template < typename T >
typename std::enable_if< test<T>::result == sizeof(__int16), int>::type call(T const& t) {
    std::cout << "In call without f available" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    Y y; X x;
    call(y);
    call(x);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code negates the whole purpose of the `sizeof` hack, which is after all used here to compare those types in the absence of `decltype`.

Comment: I don't have VS2010 around, but what about rewriting the `test` into something like: `template <typename T> struct test { static const int value = sizeof( f(T()) ); };` and then using that in the `enable_if` as: `typename enable_if< test<T>::value == sizeof(__int8), int >...`

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas Yep that seems to work too and doesn't require the decltype.  Tho I still can't explain why forcing the compiler to go through another type to get the results works.